# Can someone tell me how to properly read this explain plan. The query is taking tooo long to get the data. I am using Aurora MySQL5.7.12-log

Tags: mysql, performance, amazon-aurora

It will be great if someone show me how to optimize this further. Thank You!!

I have tried creating different indexes on all the tables also tried changing few of the global variables like buffer size etc. also tried creating the temp tables but it didn't help either.

[EXPLAIN PLAN](https://peridot-diagnostic-815.notion.site/Explain-Plan-31731a64b6c64377a027d127aee502e9)

Here I have added the query and the table details
[Query and Table Details](https://peridot-diagnostic-815.notion.site/Query-and-tables-007d6d91846a4c80a79f36780c15de25)

Comment: Please show us the query, too.  And `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table involved.  "Nested loop" implies a `JOIN`, perhaps 5 of them?  There is a `GROUP BY` and maybe an `ORDER BY`.  And please provide the simple `EXPLAIN SELECT...`; I find it easier to get started with such.

Comment: And....  There seem to be some "composite" indexes (good).  I need the query to see whether the sort can be avoided.  There seem to be a lot of indexes; perhaps some could be dropped.  "Using_index: true" means that the index was "covering" -- good.  "Convert...using" -- Sounds like mismatched charsets -- bad; possibly avoidable (need table definitions).  How many rows in the resultset?

Comment: @RickJames thanks for your response. As you said yes we have lot of indexes on our tables. I have added the query and the table details can you please take a look at it. It will be a great help if you give us some suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the `CREATE TABLEs`,

Comment: For example, what tables are `impressions` and `attributed_sales30d` in?

Comment: Usually, an `id` and a `name` are off in a "dimension" table,  But here, `ad_group_id` and `ad_group_name` are in the same `fact` table.  Please explain.  (Ditto for `campaign_id/name` and maybe others.)

Answer (score 1):

Single-column indexes are sometimes useful; 'composite' indexes are often more useful.  "Covering" may give an extra boost.  These *may* help with performance:

```
fact:     INDEX(user_id, report_type, country, brand, date)
dim:      INDEX(state, campaignId,  startDate, userId)
term:     INDEX(user_id, keyword_id, serach_term)
keyword:  INDEX(userId, keywordId,  bid, adGroupId)
adGroup:  INDEX(userId, adGroupId,  defaultBid)
```

When adding a composite index, DROP index(es) with the same leading columns.
That is, when you have both INDEX(a) and INDEX(a,b), toss the former.

Most of these suggestions are 'covering', but such is not practical for `fact` and `term`.  (I like to limit indexes to 6 columns.)  If there are any `TEXT` columns in the above indexes, then they need rethinking.  Also, I don't know what table `impressions`, etc, are in, so I did not consider whether to include them.

"buffer size":

- `key_buffer_size` applies only to ENGINE=MyISAM, which you should *not* be using.
- `innodb_buffer_pool_size` applies only to ENGINE=InnoDB; it should be set to about 70% of available RAM.  (Cloud providers seem to do this automatically.  What version of MySQL are you using?)

For reference:

```
    FROM  fact_targets_segmented_summary_daily AS `fact`
    INNER JOIN  dim_search_terms_v1 AS term
         ON term.user_id = term.user_id
        AND  term.keyword_id = fact.target_id
        AND  fact.query = term.search_term
    INNER JOIN  dim_keywords_v1 AS keyword
         ON  fact.target_id = keyword.keywordId
        AND  keyword.userId = fact.user_id
    INNER JOIN  dim_campaign_v1 AS dim
         ON  fact.campaign_id = dim.campaignId
        AND  dim.userId = fact.user_id
    INNER JOIN  dim_adgroup_v1 AS adGroup
         ON  keyword.adGroupId = adGroup.adGroupId
        AND  keyword.userId = adGroup.userId
    WHERE  (fact.user_id = {user_id}
              AND  (fact.report_type = 'keywords')
              AND  (dim.state = 'enabled')
              AND  (fact.country = {country})
              AND  (fact.brand = {brand})
              AND  fact.date BETWEEN '2022-09-18' AND '2022-10-22'
           )
```

Unfortunately, `EXPLAIN` only says what it decided to do *with the available indexes*, and does not suggest 'better' indexes.  Things I saw in your Explain:

- The tables apparently have only single-column indexes.
- Big (but not really big) numbers in the Rows column.  The product of these is a *very* crude estimate of the effort for the query.  The numbers are not big enough to alarm me.  But, since you think the query is running 'too slowly', that overrides my impression.
- The tables of `INNER JOINs` can be shuffled in many ways.  The Optimizer ponders many of them.  I saw that you had a `WHERE that referenced 2 tables, and quickly _guessed_ that` fact` (with 5 things being tested) would be a better starting point.
- Explain showed that it started with the table `dim`.  I felt that checking 5 columns in a composite index on `fact` would be a better starting table.  Notice my recommendation calls for such an index, and that the "range" (`date`) is last.  (The order of the first 4 index columns does not matter, at least not for *this* query.
- Having a better index for `fact` will [probably] push `dim` to later.  I recommend a composite index for it; the "Rows=3601" will probably decrease dramatically.
- The other tables `JOINed ON` about 2 columns, so I went for at least 2 columns in the recommended indexes.
- In Explain "Using index condition" refers to "Index condition pushdown" in the manual.  In contrast, "Using index" does not occur in your Explain, but will show up sometimes in mine.  It means that the index is "covering".  "Covering" implies that the lookup can happen entirely in the index's BTree without involving the data's BTree.
- In the JSON Explain, I see ..."grouping_operation": { "using_temporary_table": true, "using_filesort": true,...  That came from the `GROUP BY` needing to gather data in a temp, then sort it to do its job.  (More below.)  Just because it uses the word "file" does not imply that a file was used.  It may have sorted in RAM -- depending on whether `TEXT` columns were not involved and several other things.

Explode-implode -- In a query that uses both `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` may suffer from what i call "explode-implode".  This is where the query combines info from multiple tables, often creating a large temp table, then whittled it down based on the `GROUP BY`.  This can be slow.

The cure is to turn the query inside out.  (Again Explain does not tell you that.)  This is where you write a 'derived' table to find the `id` with as little effort as possible, then `JOIN` to the other tables to get the rest of the data.  This *may* avoid the `GROUP BY` altogether.  Or it may localize it to the derived table.  In either case, many fewer rows in the other tables are reached for (and re-reached for).

I do not know if the explode-implode cure is necessary for your case.  Also it may not be possible.  Your query does not group by a simple `id`, but a combination of 5 columns; that complexity is a reason for me to punt.

So, see if the indexes, alone, help enough.